# Encapsulate angular styles and scripts to component on existing website

Tags: angular

I try to describe my idea. Currently I develop Angular 7 app which will be implmmented to existing website. So it will be something like widget on existing website.

On existing website I must only create html component, for example:

```
<angular-app></angular-app>
```

and paste builded angular scripts to footer of existing website.

My problem is that angular app overrides styles and scripts of existing website. Is it possible to encapsulate Angular styles and scripts only for Angular component () , not for whole DOM ? I don't want to use iframe for this...

Thank you for your solutions.

Comment: You can simply skip importing things globally in the angular app and if your using scss/sass just use 'import' in the components styling(*.scss) your using. If you want more detail guide on how to approach your current setup, update your question with example code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what about using framework (like Bootstrap) inside Angular app? Is it possible to encapsulate it in component only?

Comment: Theoretically it is. However I'm not sure if current frameworks supports that as you usually implement it globally (or in fact is suppose to be used global, [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started) example on one of them). In general even if there was a way I wouldn't recommend injecting a whole framework into isolated parts, however if you doing like a step by step refactor/implementation there are probably best practice guides to follow.